# simple confirmation when skill completed

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm sorry if this has already been answered somewhere but honestly I am having a really hard time this morning finding the answer to this question... google isn't helping me much and neither is stack. You would think that one of the most basic things you would want Alexa to do when creating a custom skill/intent, is to confirm to the user that it "got" what you said and completed the task successfully. Strangely, I cannot find any concrete examples of how to do this?

Basically, in timeline, this is what I want my skill to do:

1. User asks: Alexa, please register {person} to the club
2. Alexa fills in slot using proper intent
3. Alexa says: Thank you! I have registered {person} into the club!

Point number 3? I cannot seem to find a way to easily do this... note that I am NOT trying to have the USER confirm something/the slot content to Alexa, but rather have ALEXA confirm to the user that the task has been completed properly.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which language you are using to develop the skill. Here I will show how I did it using python Flask-ask

```
@ask.intent('registerIntent')
def register(name):
      #do your registeration logic
      return statement('Thank you! I have registered {} into the club!'.format(name))
```

suppose you want to ask as verification before registering instead of a `return statement` you need to use `return question` so Alexa will ask are you sure you want to register user into the club, then you can write registration logic in yes intent.